# Mobileiron authorization with enterprise server

Tags: api, single-sign-on, kerberos, mdm, mobileiron

We are developing an inhouse application, which will be distrubuted via Mobileiron. I can get the active-directory/mobileiron user name and device id from mobile iron. What i need to know is, when a web service call comes to my api, i want to make sure the call is coming from a client who is logged in to my app using mobile iron. I have no idea how to do this. My manager doesn't want to use Kerberos for single sign-on and all the documents i could find contains messy information.

Can someone please show me the way in some detail? do i need to use certificate or Sentry? How should i do that?

I am running out of time so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please specify a little bit more in detail where is your web service, where is your api. Do you develop mobile app and backend web services?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you do not need to use Kerberos. You can use certificate-based authentication and have Mobile Iron configured to return the certificate. If you are using AppConnect API you can have the base-64 encoded cert (.p12) and password provided as part of the configuration object (via `AppConnect.sharedInstance().config`), which would then be passed along to the server for authentication. The LDAP user's email is embedded in the cert, so the server can associate it to a user.

There's also the option of using "pass-through" authentication which basically trusts the client is authorized. Not the safest option.